# Chain Return in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was trying to refactor code for concision. I wanted to do something like this:

```
const status = response => {
 response.status >=200 && response.status < 300 && return response;
  ... more logic here if status is not in range
  ...
  throw some error ... 
};
```

How come you aren't allowed to conditionally return like this?

Comment: `return` statement is not an expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just how the syntax works - `return` cannot be where an expression is expected, such as with an `&&` operator. `return` must always be a standalone statement. (An expression is any chunk of code that *evaluates to a value*.)

But, you can achieve what you're looking for pretty concisely with plain old `if`:

```
const status = response => {
 if (response.status >=200 && response.status < 300) return response;
  // ... more logic here if status is not in range

  throw 'some error ...'
};
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. Return isn't an expression.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you could do it in a shorthand way:

```
return (response.status >=200 && response.status < 300) ? response : 'return some magic here...'
```

Comment: But then `more magic here` must be an expression as well - additional *statements* won't work there unless you put everything into an IIFE, or something like that.

Comment: The OP didnt mentioned the else statement logic, but you are right, It depends on his needs. Just wanted to show him this option as well.